# HTML5 Doctype + JS library - necessary?

Tags: html, modernizr, html5boilerplate

In my next personal project I want to use the HTML5 doctype. I know that nearly all browsers support HTML5, even IE6 because HTML5 is downwardly compatible.

But: Do I have to use any JS library to really make it work, like HTML5shim, Modernizr or HTML5 Boilerplate (although I know that HTML5 Boilerplate isn't a library)?

I mean, what are these projects about if I don't have to use them - I've read using HTML5shim would be a so called 'best practice', is this true?
What happens if I don't use any of them? Will some browsers ignore markup-elements like `section` and `aside`?

I've also read that using these libraries is essentially bad, because if the user has deactivated JS, the site breaks - but on the other hand: Who has JS deactivated nowadays? I could just include a `noscript` tag, couldn't I?

Also, I've read in an article that these libraries cause more problems then they give us a benefit. To me it seems like the personal opinion of the author, or do they really cause so many problems?

EDIT

Alright, after testing Modernizr together with the HTML5 Boilerplate I have to say that this is a great solution so far. But one thing bugs me, I am not sure if I am doing it right.
Example: I want to use `border-radius` on a div called `#form-box`. For this example I assume that the round corners are essential for the website. If they weren't essential I wouldn't see a problem if IE users don't see them.

So I've got the class, giving the box the basic styling every browser should be able to interpret:

```
#form-box {
    background-color: #f0eeee;
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Then, for browsers that know `border-radius`:

```
.borderradius #form-box {
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android ≤1.6 */
    -moz-border-radius: 8px; /* FF1-3.6 */
    border-radius: 8px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
    /* useful if you don't want a bg color from leaking outside the border: */
    -moz-background-clip: padding; -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

And for browsers that don't know `border-radius` (i.e. the IE6), I use the polyfill "PIE" that adds round corners, even in IE using JS the .htc-file:

```
.no-borderradius #form-box {
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; /* Saf3-4, iOS 1-3.2, Android ≤1.6 */
    -moz-border-radius: 8px; /* FF1-3.6 */
    border-radius: 8px; /* Opera 10.5, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4, iOS 4, Android 2.1+ */
    /* useful if you don't want a bg color from leaking outside the border: */
    -moz-background-clip: padding; -webkit-background-clip: padding-box; background-clip: padding-box;
}
```

This is how I do it at the moment. It's cool, but: So much repeating code? Is it true that this is really neccessary? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: IE6 is NOT compatible with HTML5 and, in fact, IE<9 is not compatible because IE's CSS implementation will not work on any elements it does not recognize such as section, header, footer and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had no problems using the html5boilerplate and although I normally slim it down and remove things that aren't necessary for my projects its a great boilerplate to start with.

Comment: Thanks for you comment! Since posting here I've tested working with Modernizr. Although I felt a bit uncomfortable at first it works great so far. I've edited my first question, please take a look at it.

Comment: for browser compatibility you'll need to use the html5shim without it IE < 9 won't style elements correctly. To my knowledge it is the only real requirement to get html5 working cross browser

Comment: Well, the Modernizr Documentation says the following: 'As of Modernizr 1.5, this script is identical to what is used in the popular html5shim/html5shiv library. See http://www.modernizr.com/docs/

Comment: Whenever anyone says "cross browser" they mean "it doesn't work in IE".

Comment: Correct, if they have implemented the html5shim/html5shiv then modernizr would work. What I was saying is that modernizer isn't required to make html5 work with IE < 9 but if they've added that functionality in then you could use modernizer instead of the shiv/shim

Comment: Ah alright, that is true. @Rob: With Modernizr, you can use HTML5 elemnts in IE without any problems because JS adds these functions to the browser. So you can code HTML5 and even IE6 can understand it. Or more precisely: The JS running in IE6 understands the HTML5 syntax.

Comment: @Sven Yes, I know that, but what I said is still true.